# Quotient Ring and finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

How is a quotient ring $\mathbb Z/p^e\mathbb Z$ (where p is prime and $e>2$) different from a finite field $\mathbb F_{p^e}$? When they are both rings, have the same elements?

I thought a finite field p is generated by $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The group structure is different. All $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ are vector spaces over $\Bbb F_p$, so they are isomorphic to

$$\left(\Bbb F_p\right)^n\cong\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^n$$

as groups

Answer (score 1):

The ring $\mathbb Z/p^e\mathbb Z$ with $e\ge2$ is not a field because it has divisors of zero. Specifically, the product of $p+p^e\mathbb Z$ and $p^{e-1}+p^e\mathbb Z$ is zero. The additive group of $\mathbb F_{p^e}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^e$, whereas that of $\mathbb Z/p^e\mathbb Z$ is cyclic.

Comment: Ok that make sense, thank you very much